# Items in static List<Item>()

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference

So I have a static item list which stores a few classes, and in those classes are variables such as "int ID", "string name", "string description", "int currentAmount", etc.

```
ItemDatabase.cs...

public static List<Item> Items

static void LoadItemData()
{
    Items.Add(new item);
    ...
}
```

I then have a separate item list which will have items added to it for use by the player.

```
Player.cs...

List<Item> playerItems;
```

Then in other classes, I have `AddItem(int ID)` methods:

```
void AddItem(int id)
{
    foreach (Item i in ItemDatabase.Items)
        if (i.ID == id)
            playerItems.Add(i);
}
```

I'm currently adding in entities that will make use of the same data. But when I modify the Item added to the playerItems, it modifies ItemDatabase.Items (Obviously, due to referencing).

**I can't make the Item class into a struct, because I have other classes which derive from it.
I need the "currentAmount" integer to be by value. Is there any way I can do this?**

P.S., I've tried deep cloning, and that doesn't play nicely with my Item class.

Comment: Why doesn't cloning work?  Seems like that's the solution.  Can you shallow clone if you're just modifying value types (`string`,`int`)?

Comment: @DStanley, I tried to do a deep clone, inserting [Serializable] attributes at the top of each class, however other classes that I don't have control of like Texture2D were giving me that. I also have other classes inside the Item class. Wouldn't they be set to null if I didn't do a deep copy?

Comment: You don't _need_ to serialize to do a deep clone - serializing and deserializing is just one way.  If you're not changing reference types then I would just do a shallow clone (either manually copying property vlaues or using [`object.MemberwiseClone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DStanley, thank you so much. I tried MemberwiseClone, and it worked excellent. Do you mind putting that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you need to clone the objects if you want to change them without affecting the original.  Serialization is one way to do a "deep clone" but as you have discovered not all types can be serialized.

If you are just modifying the first-level value type properties (not changing related item's values or references) you can use [`object.MemberwiseClone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a *shallow* copy (copies of value types and references).

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate out `currentAmount`. Since that value only makes sense in the context of a `Player` *anyways*, I would take that out of the `Item` class, and use a `Dictionary<Item,int>` to keep track of the inventory:

```
Dictionary<Item, int> inventory = new Dictionary<Item, int>();

void AddItem(int id)
{
    foreach (Item i in ItemDatabase.Items)
        if (i.ID == id)
            playerItems.Add(i, 0); //Or whatever count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure where you are modifying ItemsDatabase.Items (currentAmount as property of the Entity doesn't makes much more sense), but for current amount in your Inventory, I guess this will help you:

```
Dictionary<Item, int> inventory = new Dictionary<Item, int>();

void AddItem(int id)
{
    foreach (Item i in ItemDatabase.Items)
        if (i.ID == id)
            {
              if(!inventory.Keys.Contains(i)){iventory.Add(i, 0);}
              inventory[i]+=1; //increment the amount of items in inventory.
            }
}
```

Important:

Dictionary uses Hash to get the object from dictionary, so, you probably want to override that method in your Item class:

```
class Item {
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public int currentAmount;

    public override int GetHashCode(){
       return Name.GetHashCode() + Description.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

see more:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/371348/335905

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
void AddItem(int id)
{
    var item = ItemDatabase.Items.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ID == id);
    if(item!=null){
        playerItems.Add(new Item(){ ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name, etc... })
    }
}
```